# apply a click to parent of a tag (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have alot of:

```
<li><a href="google.com">LINKY</a></li>
```

type links on my site and much prefere the whole Li to be clickable instead of just the text. So was thinking of applying some nice jquery that will  hunt any $('li a') down and make it so when you click the `<li>` it will trigger the click on a `<a>`

```
        $('li a').each(function(index) {
            $(this).parent().bind('click', function() {
                $(this).children().click();
            });
        });
```

This fails to work but im not sure why? any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered making the <a> tag a display:block, so that it fills the entire <li> ? That would be a CSS-only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick replys all! 
resolved with 

$('li:has( > a)').click(function() {
        $(this).find('a').click();
    });

Comment: @Steve - Why are you doing `$(this).find('a').click();` inside the function? What is that call meant to do?

Comment: it clicks the a tag... which takes me to where ever that a tag is href to!

Comment: @Steve - Well, just so you know, it creates an infinite loop. I didn't know the purpose of the click handler. If all you want is to go to the link, the CSS solutions may be the way to go. I'm not sure that triggering the click will take you to the link in all browsers anyway.

Comment: thanks ill look into it... looks like it doesnt work in all browsers ... mmm ideally css is the best method if i can get it working nice and pretty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler if you just bind the click event to the `<li>` element.

Event bubbling will ensure that it is triggered when you click the `<a>` as well.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MB9Fm/

```
$('li:has( > a)').click(function() {
     alert('I was clicked');
     return false;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

I may have misunderstood the intention for the `click` handler. If all you wanted to do was visit the href location, I'd agree with the CSS solutions of possible. Otherwise, using js, do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkGga/

```
$('li:has( > a)').click(function() {
     window.location = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
});
```

The way you were calling `.click()` in your comment would cause an infinite loop, an I'm not sure that it would actually take you to the href location anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be better to stretch the anchor to the size of LI?

```
li > a {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   /* optionally height: some height */
}
```

Comment: You may need to account for browsers that don't deal with child selectors (and "li a" works fine, maybe with a class somewhere in there), but otherwise this is much more robust than JavaScript. +1

Comment: would be a brilliant fix but the block messys up horizantial aligned li's!

Comment: Well, float them, or something! There are tons of ways of getting them where you want.

Answer (score 1):

Calling click() on a link doesn't perform the default action (going to the address).  You could manually make a click handler:

```
$('li a').each(function(index) {
            $(this).parent().bind('click', function() {
                window.location = $(this).children().attr('href');
            });
        });
```

Comment: @gnarf, that's true.  Can you suggest a way to better mimic the default browser behavior?

Comment: Check the `event.target.nodeName != 'A'` and it'll help on the dual open from a ctrl+click, but still not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FzaVS/

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `.delegate()` functionality added in 1.4.2, this is more suited to your desires.

```
$("li").delegate("a", "click", function(event){
  //do what you want here
  return false; //prevent default action and prevent bubbling up
});
```

Comment: note: remove the "return false;" if you DO want default action and bubbling up.

Comment: The OP wants to make the `<li>` clickable. Using `.delegate()` in this manner (even without the `return false`) will not trigger the handler when you click the `li`. Only when you click the `<a>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('li:has(a)').each(function() {
    $(this).bind('click', function(index){
        $(this).find('a').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't call `.live()` like this, it needs a selector :)